# jQuery change event always fires on radio buttons already checked

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, radio-button, onchange

I have a strange problem which already made me bang my head against the wall for hours. I'm using jQuery to add an event listener to two radio buttons inside one control group. The changed event trigger an ajax request and the answer is used to exchange a part of the webpage below the radio buttons. The radio buttons themselves are not exchanged.

jQuery Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(":input[name= 'radio-choice-h-2']").on('change', function(){
        $.post("process.php", {direction: $(this).attr("value"), lektion:$("#h1").text() + ".txt"})
            .done(function(data) {
                $(".question").html(data).trigger("create");
            })
            .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                alert(textStatus, errorThrown);
            });
    });
```

html Code:

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" style="text-align: center" id="direction">
<input name="radio-choice-h-2" id="radio-choice-h-2a" value="atob" type="radio" >
<label for="radio-choice-h-2a">a → b</label>
<input name="radio-choice-h-2" id="radio-choice-h-2b" value="btoa" type="radio">
<label for="radio-choice-h-2b">b → a</label>
</fieldset>
```

The problem is, the change event always fires even if the radio button is already checked. I also checked, if the radio buttons are really checked by logging their checked status like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(":input[name= 'radio-choice-h-2']").on('change', function(){
      console.log('#radio-choice-h-2a').is(':checked');
      console.log('#radio-choice-h-2b').is(':checked');
});
```

The Output was always

```
true
false
```

for the first button and other way round for second button. I would have expected, that this only outputs, if the values change, but it always outputs no matter if the values changed. I used jQuery 2.1.3 and the problem exists in at least Firefox and Chrome. Haven't tested others.

UPDATE:

http://jsfiddle.net/6cnLgonk/15/

See this jsfiddle. I have included the external sources of jQuery mobile. If i do this, the desired behavior disappears and the .change() event is always fired even if the radio button is already checked....

What did i miss here? Thanks for your help !!

Comment: I think this is the problem "checked="checked", can you make jsfiddle demo (by removing ajax call in it)

Comment: No sadly this doesn't fix the problem. Already removed this attribute. Didn't change anything...

Comment: _"The Output was always `true false`"_ Could not reproduce this . What is expected result ?

Comment: use `$(":input[name='radio-choice-h-2']").on('change', function(){` .remove space `:input[name= 'radio-choice-h-2'`

Comment: the expected result is ``true false`` for the first button clicked first time and ``false true`` for second button clicked first time and no output at all for any button clicked second time or more often, because this shouldn't trigger the .change()

Comment: _"and no output at all for any button clicked second time or more often, because this shouldn't trigger the .change()"_ ? Not certain interpret correctly ? Each `input` should call `change` event handler at most once ?

Comment: the change() event handler is only triggered for a radio button if it is not already checked. See this https://jsfiddle.net/6cnLgonk/6/

Comment: @trixn  _"the change() event handler is only triggered for a radio button if it is not already checked"_   `$(":input[name='radio-choice-h-2']:not(:checked)").on('change', fn)` https://jsfiddle.net/6cnLgonk/7/ ?

Comment: @guest   your fiddle shows the same behavior but outputting to console instead showing an alert box... what can i learn from this now?

Comment: @trixn Still not exactly certain what expected result is ? https://jsfiddle.net/6cnLgonk/7/ adjusted `js` for _"the change() event handler is only triggered for a radio button if it is not already checked"_ ; though appear removed `checked="checked"` from `html` at jsfiddle ?

Comment: @guest as i said in my post: only the first click on the unselected radio button should trigger the .change() event and show some output. on my page, it ALWAYS trigger no matter if the radio button is already checked and therefor doesn't change....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80786/discussion-between-trixn-and-guest271314).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay after testing a bit, i found out, that the reason for this misbehavior was jQuery-mobile. Every time, i included the jQuery-mobile JS, the misbehavior showed. I had a look inside the source code and found that all input elements are replaced with styled labels by the jQuery-mobile JS hiding the original input field. The problem is, that radio-button and checkbox-buttons click events are handled together. Every time, a click event is triggered on a label, the changed event is fired on the hidden input, no matter if it is a radio-/checkbox button and no matter if it was checked before the click. I opened an issue for this bug. Answer was, the bug will not be fixed, because the next jQuery-mobile release will have different components for radio/checkbox buttons which do not suffer from this issue.

Answer (score 1):

> only the first click on the unselected radio button should trigger the
>   .change() event and show some output. on my page, it ALWAYS trigger no
>   matter if the radio button is already checked and therefor doesn't
>   change

Try utilizing selector `$(":input[name='radio-choice-h-2']:not(:checked)")` ; substituting `.one()` for `.on()`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(":input[name='radio-choice-h-2']:not(:checked)").on('change', function(e){
      console.log(this.value
                  , $('#radio-choice-h-2a').is(':checked')
                  , $('#radio-choice-h-2b').is(':checked'));
     //   alert($('#radio-choice-h-2a').is(':checked'));
     //   alert($('#radio-choice-h-2a').is(':checked'));
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" style="text-align: center" id="direction">
  <input name="radio-choice-h-2" id="radio-choice-h-2a" value="atob" type="radio" checked="checked">
  <label for="radio-choice-h-2a">a → b</label>
  <input name="radio-choice-h-2" id="radio-choice-h-2b" value="btoa" type="radio">
  <label for="radio-choice-h-2b">b → a</label>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: this doesn't solve my problem because the radio buttons should work all the time if not checked, with one() they only work once.

Comment: @trixn See updated post. With `html` at original post , only second `input` change event would be called. Is this expected result ?

Comment: No, the expected behavior is the one in this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/6cnLgonk/6/ which i already posted. The event should ALWAYS fire when i switch the radio buttons. MY PROBLEM IS: i believe my code is the same, as the fiddle but on my page, it doesn't work. What can be the reason for this?

Comment: @trixn Had same selector at both `alert` calls; see https://jsfiddle.net/6cnLgonk/10/ . Does https://jsfiddle.net/6cnLgonk/10/ resolve Question ?

Comment: No i doesn't have the same selectors on both alert calls and no it doesn't solve my problem because as i said several times before: I know this fiddle works and it exactly shows the desired behaviour, but about the same code on my page doesn't. My question is, what could be the reason for this?

Comment: @trixn Selectors not appear same at `alert` , there, at https://jsfiddle.net/6cnLgonk/6/ ? Not certain why expected result not returned at page ? Is all `js` run at page included at Question ? Or are portions not included at OP ?

Comment: and even i they have the same selectors: they only output if the radio button is not checked, which is the desired behaviour

Comment: @trixn Not following ? `js` at OP should return expected results. Perhaps other `js` not included at OP affecting outcome ?

Comment: everything relevant is in my initial post. there is another js .on('click') call which sets the event handler for a button but thats all. I will post it in the chat because we start abusing the comment area ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80789/discussion-between-trixn-and-guest271314).

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is your jQ - with some slight tweaking , I have it working here:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vOJPMR

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(":input[name='radio-choice-h-2']").on('change', function(){
      console.log($('#radio-choice-h-2a').is(':checked'));
      console.log($('#radio-choice-h-2b').is(':checked'));
  });
});
```

Your selector & console log statements were not well-formed, but with the above CodePen, the log statements are only triggered when a change is made; nothing appears in the console if clicking the currently selected radio button repeatedly.

Comment: in jsfiddle my code also shows the desired behavior. That's the problem. But without the ajax inside the event handler...

Comment: @trixn With `$.ajax()` inside event handler , what is issue or error ?

Comment: @guest271314 inside the event handler a ajax request is made with $.post and the answer is used to exchange some html inside the page. see my code in initial question. I can not reproduce this error in jsfiddle and i don't know why because i can't see, what makes the difference.

Comment: @trixn What is _"the difference"_ ? Is expected result that each input call `change` event at most _once_ ?

Comment: between the code which is working in jsfiddle but not on my page  ????.... The only thing, that is different in jsfiddle to my code is, that the event handler does't make an ajax request but outputs to console. But this shouldn't change the way, the event is triggered